# ST_Intersects one polygon with layer - always returns 0 results

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I'm trying to write a query to find if any features in a layer intersect with a certain polygon, but it is always returning 0 rows. I've tried messing with SRIDs, different geom types, sizes, shapes, etc. and have never had it return a single result, making me think there is just a basic misunderstanding I'm having.

The geometry data in the database is stored under the "geometry" column in the WKT format with the 3857 SRID. All I want to is to get returned all the rows whose geometry touches the polygon at all.

The query I wrote looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOfFeatures
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=3857;POLYGON((-118.09636448889168 83.80774305261292, -103.722647355961 -83.72028886793554, -13.87670908426287 -83.7764092545634, -38.85866039455652 84.01409674357751, -118.09636448889168 83.80774305261292))'), geometry);
```

Am I missing some kind of conversion or cast?

Comment: Your polygon seems to be in SRID 4326 (geographic coordinates), not 3857.

Comment: @Mesa ah yeah, but when I change it to 'SRID=4326' it still doesn't return anything. You can see that polygon takes up half the map, and the layer has points everywhere. Maybe I don't understand exactly how the projections convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to Transform from 4326 to 3857 projection.

Thanks to @Mesa for getting me going in the right direction.

Here's what ended up working

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOfFeatures
WHERE st_intersects(geometry,
                ST_Transform(
                  ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-118.09636448889168 83.80774305261292, -103.722647355961 -83.72028886793554, -13.87670908426287 -83.7764092545634, -38.85866039455652 84.01409674357751, -118.09636448889168 83.80774305261292))')
                  , 3857)
      )
```